# Volume odoo. Permission issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, odoo

Ubuntu 18.04. I am using [odoo docker files](https://github.com/odoo/docker/tree/master/13.0)

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: ./build 
#    image: odoo:13.0
#    user: root
    depends_on:
      - mydb
    ports:
      - "18275:8069"
    environment:
      - HOST=mydb
      - USER= us
      - PASSWORD=pw
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./odoo:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./extra-addons:/mnt/extra-addons
  mydb:
    image: postgres:12.1
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pw
      - POSTGRES_USER=us
    restart: always
```

In ./build directory I have docker files from odoo github repository.

I have problems with `volumes: ./odoo:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo`

My odoo container is restarting with logs:

```
web_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1   |   File "/usr/bin/odoo", line 8, in <module>
web_1   |     odoo.cli.main()
web_1   | AttributeError: module 'odoo' has no attribute 'cli'
```

I think it's permission issue. I added some permission, I changed user and group owner and nothing...

What should I do to create this volume?

Without this one volume everything works great

Comment: Using a Docker volume to overwrite a library in the system tree is likely to run into exactly this sort of problem, especially if the source tree isn't directly usable in this location (I wouldn't expect this to work with most Python libraries).  Writing a derived image that `pip install`ed your updated library would work better.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, in most cases this is a good suggestion, but not for `odoo`, because this framework usually installed not through `pip`.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0XpG4S6jNQM In this short video someone made it , but he didn't say how did it.

Comment: My docker-compose looks very similar - and it is working great.  This is the correct way to get your persistent data in an Odoo Container.  Maybe try a different Odoo image?  I built mine from scratch and had no problems.  (I am seeing this error today in my non-docker odoo which I am installing from git - so maybe it's an odoo bug?)

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry my answer is so late - maybe we can help someone else who has this error.*

Consider how simple Odoo-bin is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# set server timezone in UTC before time module imported
__import__('os').environ['TZ'] = 'UTC'
import odoo

if __name__ == "__main__":
```

This error: `"odoo has no attribute 'cli'"` can happen if the odoo program files are not where Odoo-bin expects them to be.  The fifth line in Odoo-bin is 'import odoo', and if it isn't there, you will get this error.

And as you have guessed, if your odoo user doesn't have permissions to READ the odoo files, Odoo-bin will also throw this error when it cannot import from a folder it cannot even see.

Comment: Do You know how to fix it?

Comment: You need to decide if the problem is missing files (did you move them?) or permissions.  When you created your odoo folder structure, did you remember to chown to the user that will be executing odoo?